# Clicking on top bar drop-down buttons too early results in a random page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, top-bar

I frequently use high-latency (and often low-throughput) connections while traveling. When using StackExchange, I often want to use the top-right menu to see which posts of mine recently got upvoted, or use them to get somewhere like the site's chat. If I am too fast, clicking the correct button will bring me to a random page where I cannot do what I intended. For example, clicking the 'recent upvotes' button will bring me to my profile where I would have to click through to another page to get to those posts, and clicking the sites button to go to chat brings me to the front page of stackexchange.com.

I can think of a few possible solutions:

- Somehow indicate when javascript has loaded, perhaps by fading them in or out a little, or perhaps the "you have upvotes" button could be animated (that wouldn't help me in the chat case, but it would work for some cases).
- Use good ol' CSS drop-down menus instead of JS. I don't know how well these work compared to JS', as I last looked into this years ago and things have changed quite a bit with CSS3.
- Don't make the buttons clickable until Javascript has loaded. To make it work for people with Javascript disabled completely, `<noscript><a href=...>` should work. I think this is the best solution (easy to implement, no different UX).

Comment: This is known and by design. The pages are specifically chosen, not random.